# How do you change an open file into a list in Python?

Tags: python, database, list, import

How do I change an open file into a list in Python? For example if I'm taking a file with random information and I wanted to change it to something I can use and change the values. How can I do that in Python?

Comment: You can't import it.... That's only for valid Python programs. You open it and parse the contents it Python data structures. How you do that depends on the data.

Comment: Why is this question is not unanswerable, the file I need to open is a stat sheet, that I can go through and change the data and update the new data.

Comment: Okay, now you provided some information. Before you said random data. We are not a guessing service. You need to post something specific, preferably with code you've already tried.

Comment: Consider that none of us know what a stat sheet is.

Comment: I appreciate your advice, but I don't have any code because I don't know how to do it, therefore I asked the question.

Comment: If it's textual data, how about posting a few lines so we can see what it is. Some example to get us started.

Comment: Read & parse the file. To say anything beyond that, some information about its format is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use
        data = file.read()
to read the contents of the entire file and then 
        array = data.split('\n')
to split into separate values. Alternatively, you could use 
        array = data.readlines()
or 
        for a in data.readlines()
if your file is definitely split by newline characters.

Comment: Okay, this is the forth answer to do the exact same thing. Suppose is is an excel spreadsheet. Would this be the right way to handle the data?

Comment: Probably not - you'll have to know the format of the file you are trying to open. This includes text tagging, data structuring and maybe encryption

Answer (score 1):

You need to open a file and read it line by line, perfoming some actions on each line:

```
with open('foo.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
       dostuff(line)
```

Comment: OP never mentioned textual data. Wouldn't work with a database file.

Comment: @tdelaney, I agree, but usually when we say file we mean text file, db - database, image - image.

Comment: What? "File" is about as generic as it gets.

Comment: @tdelaney, google for `python working with files`, you will see working with text files, because when speaking about files we usually mean text files. If one were to ask about db file, he wouldn't write `how to read from database file`, just `how to read from database`. Don't you think so?

Comment: Python has modules for csv, json, bson, xml, ini, yaml, sqlite, odt, doc, xls, jpeg, png, zip, tar, diff, pdf, tex, tiff, access, .... the list goes on. My personal guess is that OP has an Excel file, seems like a natural way to track stats. The point is, the question is too vague to answer.

Answer (score 1):

I presume that you want each new line to be a new entry in the list?
This would do that:

```
ls = []
f = open("yourfile.txt", "r")
for line in f:
    ls.append(line)
```

Comment: That's only appropriate for line oriented data. Wouldn't work with say a jpeg. It's an unanswerable question.

Comment: True. I was presuming text files.

Comment: It's all speculation. I think it's best if we don't answer unanswerable questions.